# Complete Multiple Value autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I am trying to create an auto-complete textbox based on an API. I came across [this](https://github.com/jagdeep-singh/angularMultipleSelect) and it works really well.

However, there are some limitations:

1) The whole list from the API's response will be provided in one go. Imagine if there were a million items

2) When an item is typed but not selected from the dropdown list, there isn't a logic to handle that (try it on Stack Overflow Tags section - you can start typing and put a "comma" and it will become a tag)

Can someone suggest an auto-complete module which does the following:

1) Supports multiple-value autocompletion (just like the Tags on Stack Overflow) based on an API where the API's parameter is the value being typed

2) Supports the scenario of unmatched keywords

My stack:
AngularJS, MondoDB and NodeJS (with Express)

My Tags data looks like this:

```
[
{"name":"tag1"},
{"name":"tag2"},
{"name":"tag3"}
]
```

And the below is how I have implemented the module:

```
<multiple-autocomplete ng-model="post.tags" object-property="name" api-url="/api/searchAllTags"></multiple-autocomplete>
```

I am very desperate as I have been stuck on this for more than two weeks without any leads. Any input will help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here by asking on [Quora](http://www.uqora.com) instead. Have a look at this jQuery module:

https://select2.github.io/ - it has all the features a full autocomplete tagging system will need.